# Quickly count non empty cells in large excel sheet

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to determine how much data is missing from a large excel sheet. The following code takes a prohibitive amount of time to complete. I've seen similar questions, but I'm not sure how to translate the answer to this case. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C://Users/Alec/Documents/Vertnet master list.xlsx', read_only = True)
sheet = wb.active

lat = 0
loc = 0
ele = 0

a = openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string('CF')
b = openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string('BU')
c = openpyxl.utils.cell.column_index_from_string('BX')

print('Workbook loaded')

for x in range(2, sheet.max_row):
    if sheet.cell(row = x, column = a).value:
        lat += 1
    if sheet.cell(row = x, column = b).value:
        loc += 1
    if sheet.cell(row = x, column = c).value:
        ele += 1
    print((x/sheet.max_row) * 100, '%')
print('Latitude: ', lat/sheet.max_row)
print('Location', loc/sheet.max_row)
print('Elevation', ele/sheet.max_row)
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the cells left on the whole sheet (sooo many) or just the cells left in a table you have on the sheet (significantly less)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to do the calc on a table on the sheet and not the entire sheet, you could make one adjustment to make it faster.

```
row = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(range("A1").offset(row,1).value)
     if range("B"&row).value: lat += 1 
     if range("C"&row).value: loc += 1 
     if range("D"&row).value: ele += 1 
     row = row + 1
     Loop
```

This would take you to the end of your defined table rather than the end of the whole sheet which is 90% of the reason it's taking you so long.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying to count non-empty cells in 3 columns of interest that span the whole sheet, about 250k rows.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your data, is there gaps? Is there at least one column that has a value for every cell or not? With this I can propose another solution.

Comment: Yeah, every row will have at least value. In fact, there's one column with no gaps at all. The others, especially the three I'm interested in, have plenty of gaps, and I'm just trying to figure out how many gaps there are in each of those three columns.

Comment: Ok so, you can use the range code I have there on the column that doesn't have any gaps, that way it will select the total range , or you could do a do until loop, and do until the cell in the column is empty

Comment: Oh, ok, cool! I'm still not sure how that line works. Would you be able to add it into the code I posted above? And if you could explain to me a bit about what it's doing, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, despite advice in the documentation to the contrary, you're using your own counters to access cells. In read-only mode each use of `ws.cell()` will force the worksheet to reparse the XML source for the worksheet. Simply use `ws.iter_rows(min_col=a, max_col=c)` to get the cells in the columns you're interested in.